Create CloudWatch Metrics to monitor Volume in Available state
I'm trying to create a metric to see all the EBS volumes in available state. I'm want a widget/dashboard for that, because this way I did it's not possible to create an alarm for the graphic.
What I have managed to do until now was to create a Lambda function that describe all EBS volumes and send the info about the 'Volume State' to a log group. After that I used the Log Insights and I query to filter and count the "Available" in the log. That worked, but I want to know if there's other way to do that.
This is the Query I used in the Logs Insights:
parse @message "Volume ID: *, Volume State: " as volumeId, volumeState
| filter volumeState == "available"
| stats count() as availableVolumes by bin(5m)
And this an example of what my Lambda function sends to the Log Group:

Volume ID: vol-xxxxxx, Volume State: in-use
Volume ID: vol-xxxxxa, Volume State: Available


Try adding a trigger: in the trigger configuration window add an eventbridge, and create a rule based on an event type for your lambda function work and for what you're to accomplish or the event trigger. I hope this might also help:
AWS:Lambda: Add SNS trigger programmatically
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sns-example.html

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I managed to do it using put_metric_data from Boto3.
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudwatch/client/put_metric_data.html
